# Unable to click button using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

The webelement button is loaded but still unable to click it. Below is the html code of the button.

How to handle this?

```html
<button type="button" aria-label="Google Pay" class="gpay-card-info-container black buy long en"><div class="gpay-card-info-animation-container black gpay-card-info-animation-container-fade-out"><div class="gpay-card-info-placeholder-container"><div class="
    gpay-card-info-animation-gpay-logo black
    "></div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" direction="ltr" height="36px" width="130px"><style>@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Google+Sans:500)</style><line x1="2" y1="10.5" x2="2" y2="29.5" style="stroke: #5F6368; stroke-width:2"></line><image x="11" y="6" width="37.5" height="29" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/payment_white_36dp.png"></image><text x="52" y="25.5" class="small" style="font: 15px 'Google Sans', sans-serif; fill: #FFFFFF">••••••</text></svg></div><div class="gpay-card-info-animated-progress-bar-container"><div class="gpay-card-info-animated-progress-bar"><div class="gpay-card-info-animated-progress-bar-indicator"></div></div></div></div><iframe class="gpay-card-info-iframe gpay-card-info-iframe-fade-in" scrolling="no" src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/generate_gpay_btn_img?buttonColor=default&amp;browserLocale=en&amp;buttonSizeMode=static&amp;enableGpayNewButtonAsset=false"></iframe></button>
```

Comment: Please share all your Selenium code including a link to the page you are working on

Comment: Check for iframes too.

Comment: @Prophet Thanks for your reply. It is fixed now using action class.